# retaining plist but loosing plist values

Tags: iphone, ios, plist

I am creating a plist to save some values, however during testing I have noted that I retain my newly created plist after the application is closed & removed from multitasking. However I loose my values inside that plist if the application is removed from multitasking but not if the app is closed...

This is the save data method I have in my plist controller class thats managing all of the read/write/save etc.

```
- (void) saveData:(NSString *)methodName signature:(NSString *)pSignature Version:(NSNumber *)pVersion request:(NSNumber *)rNumber dataVersion:(NSNumber *)dvReturned cacheValue:(NSNumber *)cValue;
    {
        // get paths from root direcory
        NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains (NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
        // get documents path
        NSString *documentsPath = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
        // get the path to our Data/plist file
        NSString *plistPath = [documentsPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"EngineProperties.plist"];

        // set the variables to the values in the text fields
        self.signature = pSignature;
        self.version = pVersion;
        self.request = rNumber;
        self.dataVersion = dvReturned;

        //do some if statment stuff here to put the cache in the right place or what have you.
        if (methodName == @"manu")
        {
            self.man = cValue; 
        }
        else if (methodName == @"models")
        {
            self.mod = cValue;
        }
        else if (methodName == @"subMod")
        {
            self.sub = cValue;
        }

        self.cacheValue = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                           man, @"Manu",
                           mod, @"Models",
                           sub, @"SubModels", nil];


        NSDictionary *plistDict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                   signature, @"Signature",
                                   version, @"Version",
                                   request, @"Request",
                                   dataVersion, @"Data Version",
                                   cacheValue, @"Cache Value", nil];



        NSString *error = nil;
        // create NSData from dictionary
        NSData *plistData = [NSPropertyListSerialization dataFromPropertyList:plistDict format:NSPropertyListXMLFormat_v1_0 errorDescription:&error];

        // check is plistData exists
        if(plistData)
        {
            // write plistData to our Data.plist file
            [plistData writeToFile:plistPath atomically:YES];

            NSString *myString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:plistData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
            //        NSLog(@"%@", myString);
        }
        else
        {
            NSLog(@"Error in saveData: %@", error);
            //        [error release];
        }
    }


    @end
```

My question has two parts.. 
Can I save the values so they are retained in the plist even when the app is removed from the multitaksing bar.
what do I need to change to get this to work if it can work?

Comment: Probably not the issue, but you can just call writeToFile: on your dictionary, and it will be output as a plist.

Comment: You're saving to the filename `EngineProperties.plist`, but your comment think it's saving `Data.plist`.  What filename are you loading?  Also, when you save the file, log `plistPath`.  If you run your app in the simulator, you can go to the path in the finder and see what files were created, and open them in XCode to see their contents.

Comment: opps comment was wrong.. I updated it with a more descriptive name. One question however is where is the path in finder? I have not heard of this before?

Answer (score 0):

This probably has to do with where the saveData method is being called. Check out the app delegate, there are a few stubs in the by default. You probably want applicationWillResignActive, applicationDidEnterBackground or applicationWillTerminate. Check the documentation for each, the one you want will depend on when you want the data to be written.

Comment: right so you think I should call this method when one of those appdelegate methods are called.. is there a special way I need to call it (i.e. not create another instance) or dose that not matter so long as I call this method.

Comment: The thing being, that savedata method is being called everytime I add a new value to the plist.. and when testing I made sure all values were saved and they were still removed when the app was deleted from multi tasking......